# Is it possible to aim or do called shots when fanning?

Tags: savage-worlds, deadlands-reloaded, locational-damage, shooting

In Savage Worlds Deluxe / Deadlands Reloaded, can a gunslinger fanning his pistol aim a round (-2) first, and/or can he try to hit vitals/heads (called shot) during fanning?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you are allowed to Aim before Fanning the Hammer as long as all your shots are at the same target. The +2 bonus you get from Aiming is applied to all of your Shooting Die and Wild Die. This effectively means that the bonus reduces the penalty for Fanning the Hammer from -4 to -2.

Yes you can attempt to hit a particular part of a target with your shots, and as long as you are NOT combining this with Aiming as described in the previous paragraph, you can choose to spread your shots around. For example, you could fire one shot at the head, another at an arm etc etc.

See [here](https://www.peginc.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=27584&highlight=fan%20hammer%20aim) for confirmation on the use of Aim with Fanning the Hammer.

Answer (score -1):

While it is not explicitly stated in the base rules, I would allow both.

- In case of the aiming maneuver, the player sacrificed his previous round to aim, and I don't see a reason why the first shot shouldn't benefit from this. So -2 for the first bullet. (Edit: Marksman is irrelvant, limits you to RoF 1).
- For called shot/rapid shot combos, your penalty gets really bad. -8 means you have to roll 12 to hit, and you have only a single wild die for all shots combined, so yes, by all means, *try* it. It will be awesome for the PC if he lands a hit...

Comment: I think that your answer was downvoted because it didn't include an official ruling, just your opinion.

Comment: @Thunderforge: That might be, but I can't find anything in the written rules that clears this question, and unless they write an official addendum/correction to this, that's all we got. And no, I don't consider a forum post an official ruling, even if it is on the Pinnacle forum.

Comment: @Sven the forum answer I quote is by Clint Black. He is the official Pinnacle Games source for all rules questions and clarifications on Savage Worlds and their other products. When he posts an answer on the 'Official Answers on How the Rules In Other Pinnacle Products Work' or 'Official Answers on How the Rules In Other Pinnacle Products Work' sub-forums, they ARE official rulings